# Why is a verb omitted in English coordination?

Tags: verbs

In English coordination, it is very common that a verb should be omitted so that the whole expression sounds natural as exemplifed below.

- *Ann came with, and Bob without, a date.* (Langacker 2012).

This omission is very strange for a non-native speaker.
What motivates this verb *came* not to occur again prior to without?

Comment: Note that the noun phrase _a date_ has also been omitted from the first conjunct. More is going on than verb omission in the second conjunct.

Comment: This only sounds strange to a non-native speaker whose own language doesn’t allow this kind of omission of repeated content – and there are lots of other languages apart from English that _do_ (mutatis mutandis). Offhand, I can’t think of any Western European languages that wouldn’t allow similar constructions. (I’m excluding Basque here, ’cause I don’t know nearly enough about it to know either way.)

Comment: "For an non-native speaker." As Janus said, plenty of other languages do this. Perhaps it would be more helpful if you list what languages cannot.